# How to adjust select of a function

Tags: r

Could you help me solve the problem below: as you can see in the second part of the code I exclude the DR that have all columns that are equal to 0. However, in the third part of the code, I need to select D1 until the last column DR, for the sum to be done. But it gives an error, could you help me solve the problem?

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       D1 = c(2,3,4,4,6,3,4,5,6,2), DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,2), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4,4,3),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5,4,3),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,3,6,2,1,9,2),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9,3,4),
       DR06 = c(2,4,4,3,3,5,6,7,8,3),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8,3,3),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0),DR09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR010 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR011 = c(0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), DR012 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df1<-df1 %>%
  select(!where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0)))

df1<-df1 %>%
  group_by(date1,date2, Week) %>%
  select(D1:DR012) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have the `select` before

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   select(date1, date2, Week, matches("^D")) %>%
   group_by(date1, date2, Week) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 13
  date1      date2      Week        D1  DR01  DR02  DR03  DR04  DR05  DR06  DR07  DR08 DR011
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02 Friday       5     5     6    14     9     9     6     7     0     4
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday     4     4     6     4     3     5     4     4     0     0
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday     4     3     7     3     3     3     3     4     0     0
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09 Friday       6     3     3     3     3     6     3     9     1     0
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday     3     4     2     2     6     2     5     4     2     0
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday     4     3     7     1     2     1     6     7     0     0
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02 Friday       5     6     4     5     1     9     7     8     0     0
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03 Saturday     8     5     7     7    11     7    11     6     0     0
```

---

After we did the `select`, it is not clear why we have to `select` again.  It is not really needed as `summarise` with `across` can be `everything()` other than the grouping columns

```
df1 %>% 
    select(!where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0))) %>% 
    group_by(across(date1:Week)) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 8 × 13
  date1      date2      Week        D1  DR01  DR02  DR03  DR04  DR05  DR06  DR07  DR08 DR011
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02 Friday       5     5     6    14     9     9     6     7     0     4
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday     4     4     6     4     3     5     4     4     0     0
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday     4     3     7     3     3     3     3     4     0     0
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09 Friday       6     3     3     3     3     6     3     9     1     0
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday     3     4     2     2     6     2     5     4     2     0
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday     4     3     7     1     2     1     6     7     0     0
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02 Friday       5     6     4     5     1     9     7     8     0     0
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03 Saturday     8     5     7     7    11     7    11     6     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `summarise` with `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  select(!where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0))) %>% 
  group_by(date1,date2, Week) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

```
        date1      date2     Week D1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR011
1  2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday  2    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0     0
2  2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday  3    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0     4
3  2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday  4    4    6    4    3    5    4    4    0     0
4  2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday  4    3    7    3    3    3    3    4    0     0
5  2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday  6    3    3    3    3    6    3    9    1     0
6  2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday  3    4    2    2    6    2    5    4    2     0
7  2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday  4    3    7    1    2    1    6    7    0     0
8  2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday  5    6    4    5    1    9    7    8    0     0
9  2021-06-28 2021-07-03 Saturday  6    3    4    4    9    3    8    3    0     0
10 2021-06-28 2021-07-03 Saturday  2    2    3    3    2    4    3    3    0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

`DR012` is filtered, so it does not exist anymore to `select`:

```
df1 %>% 
  select(!where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. == 0))) %>% 
  names()

 [1] "date1" "date2" "Week"  "D1"    "DR01"  "DR02"  "DR03"  "DR04"  "DR05" 
[10] "DR06"  "DR07"  "DR08"  "DR011"
```

Change your code to

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(date1,date2, Week) %>%
  select(D1:DR011) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```

or

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(date1,date2, Week) %>%
  select(starts_with("D")) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```